# Easy way to modify CSS layout without coding?

Tags: css

I am maintaining a page that is basically like a wiki, for my internal site.

I would like to change the layout of one of our report pages, but they are made in CSS

Is there any way to modify CSS styles without having to necessarily code by hand and spend time with tables and measurements? I have tried to change by hand values and order of tables but the results are far from being satisfactory (left HTML and web coding behind almost 12 years ago).

Is there any app that allows me to load the CSS style, re-arrange items and sections on the page visually (kinda like you would do in a UI editor like VisualStudio), and allows you to put more sections or elements on the page?

I may go for the route of coding the CSS style, but would love to save time learning something that I will most likely not use for long time (I work as programmer for C++ language, so basically once every 4 years or so).

Comment: A drag and drop interface will not be as powerful and won't be able to deal with many of the nuances of CSS. I've never heard of a professional UI coder that uses a WYSIWYG, they are fine for simple layouts, but never good enough for a large application with fluid layouts. I also find that I can achieve results faster by hand coding.

Comment: Indeed, but I am not a professional UI coder for CSS :) Most of my work is done in C++, the site is just to deliver the results from the database of the app, and present the info in a nice way. Other than that I do not touch anything on the site part; left everything as it was.

It is just frustrating for me to have to deal with the data in the current layout, so I was planning to move things around to make it prettier. I get your point, but I just feel like a waste of time to learn something that I will never use for my profession :) Thanks for the reply!

Comment: If the existing CSS is too complicated, a WYSIWYG probably couldn't deal with it well. WYSIWYGs usually only work only with code they themselves generated. If it's simple CSS, it should be simple to edit. If you are truly not that comfortable with learning basic CSS, you should ask someone who is more comfortable to do it. If there isn't anyone, you're out of luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome and Firefox have some really nice tools to find css for the elements on the page and rearrange things in the browser so you can see how they will look with the changes.  Pretty simple to just create a new css file based on the changes you make in the browser and link the page to that new css file without doing much manual coding.

Comment: To be fair, you will still have to know a thing or two about CSS with this method.  As a recommendation, I'd take the time to learn CSS.  It's currently a HUGE plus on any developer's resume.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was not aware that you can do that in Firefox...Will try it and see if it is quick enough for my purpose, Thanks!

Agree Joe, at least I gotta know the basics, but I would gladly avoid the measuring and tweaking part using code only....we do not code in that way in almost any language anymore (unless you use the old Java libraries....other than that Visual C++, Visual C# and other visual editors uses the movable/resizable objects paradigm all via visual interface, and is a blessing).

Answer (score 0):

use web-developer(f12) with chrome or firebug in firefox.you can add/remove/modify css styles in the web page in real time

firebug : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I think that this is the same that Steven mentioned in the previous reply.